# Oracle Insert, Update, Delete Trigger with Join

Tags: oracle, join, triggers

I'm trying to implement Oracle triggers for child views but I need to be able to join the child views to their parents in order to do a role permission check.

In SQL Server I'm able to stuff like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ASetTrt_I] ON [dbo].[UCV_ASet_TRT]
                INSTEAD OF Insert AS   
                BEGIN   
                    SET NOCOUNT ON;    
                    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 from INSERTED i INNER JOIN [Analysis_Sets] p on i.[key] = p.[ID] 
                        WHERE ([dbo].IsMemberOf(p.[UpdateRole]) <> 1 and [dbo].IsMemberOf('db_owner') <> 1))
                            RAISERROR ('Update failed due to insufficient permission',11,1)
                    INSERT INTO [Set_Trts] ( [ID], [Name], [key], [f_lTreatmentKey], [f_lOrder] ) 
                    SELECT 
                    inserted.[ID], inserted.[Name], inserted.[key], inserted.[f_lTreatmentKey], inserted.[f_lOrder]                               
                    FROM inserted 
                    INNER JOIN [Sets] parentT 
                        on inserted.[key] = parentT.[ID]
                    WHERE (([dbo].IsMemberOf('db_owner')=1) or ([dbo].IsMemberOf(parentT.[UpdateRole])=1))
                END
```

Is there anything I can do in Oracle to replicate the join functionality?

I've tried selecting from :New the way that SS selects from inserted but that doesn't seem to work..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to join. The`:new` pseudorow is just available and can be referenced like a record type. It isn't a table-like structure, and is only available in a `for each row` trigger. So your insert would be something like:

```
INSERT INTO Analysis_Set_Trts ( ID, Name, f_lAnalysisSetKey, f_lTreatmentKey,
  f_lOrder ) 
SELECT :new.ID, :new.Name, :new.f_lAnalysisSetKey, :new.f_lTreatmentKey,
  :new.f_lOrder                            
FROM Analysis_Sets parentT 
WHERE parentT.ID = :new.f_lAnalysisSetKey
AND ((IsMemberOf('db_owner')=1) or (IsMemberOf(parentT.UpdateRole)=1));
```

... although not quite sure what the last line is doing or what the equivalent is.